# Spring PROPAGATION_REQUIRED.. joined

Tags: spring, transactions

Im using Spring and have two methods which are using declarative transaction...

in some cases methodA calls methodB.. what i need to know is in declarative trasaction does the commit occur twice...

example

```
public void methodA() throws Exception {

            this.transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED)
                final Order order = this.transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Order>() {
                    @Override
                    public Order doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                            Order order = new Order();
                            String name = "Customer 2 " + (new Date()).toLocaleString();
                            order.setCustomer(name);                                                            
                            entityManager.persist(order);
                         ..........................
                           .......................
                         // call methodB
                        methodB();

 }

public void methodB() throws Exception {


this.transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
                    final Address add = this.transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Address >() {
                        @Override
                        public Order doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                                Address add= new Address ();
                                add.setAddress("address");                                                          
                                entityManager.persist(add);

                        ......................
                        .....................
    }
```

By using PROPOGATION_REQUIRED, the transaction in methodB will join the transaction started in methodA.

But would this mean that the transaction is committed twice?

I added sychronizer to the transaction in methodB :

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization(){

                    public void afterCommit() {
                        System.out.println("====> AFTER SUCCESSFUL COMMIT 2 TO DB..."); 


                    }
```

I added sychronizer to the transaction in methodA :

TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronization(){

```
                public void afterCommit() {
                    System.out.println("====> AFTER SUCCESSFUL COMMIT 1 TO DB..."); 


                }
```

The output i got was after methodA completed::

```
====> AFTER SUCCESSFUL COMMIT 2 TO DB...
====> AFTER SUCCESSFUL COMMIT 1 TO DB...
```

I guess this means that two sycnronisers have been assigned tot he trans..manager, and when the commit occurs once... both synchronisers are called?.. correct?

Comment: whether ` methodB();` is called with in the `doInTransaction(){}` of `methodA()`

Comment: i believe when the transaction in methodA completes.. and is ready to commit it will first call commit on methodB transaction and then commit on methodA transaction... any failures will roll back both...any commit hooks will called in reverse order too.. methodB hooks followed by methodA hooks.. am i right?

Comment: since you are using `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` there will not be two different transaction, both methods will be running within the same transaction. If you look at the definition of `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` it says `Support a current transaction; create a new one if none exists.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` there will not be two different transaction, both methods will be running within the same transaction. If you look at the definition of `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` it says

> Support a current transaction; create a new one if none exists.

.

So if `methodB` completes successfully then it will not commit the transaction, but if it fails it will mark the transaction as `rollback-only`. The responsibility to actually commit or rollback will be on the the guy who created the transaction. In your case it will be on `methodA`

Comment: yes i agree, started adding sychronisation hooks to check the behavior... and you were right. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: This does not seem to be true anymore, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817664/spring-hibernate-manually-creating-transactions-propagation-required-fails-b