# Spring + Hibernate manually creating transactions, PROPAGATION_REQUIRED fails. BUG?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

**PLEASE DO NOT RECOMMEND THAT I USE TRANSACTION ANNOTAIONS FOR THIS.**

I have run into what appears to be a bug, related to Spring handling of transactions.

Please have a look at these two test cases, comments are in the code:

Entity class for example:

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @Id
    String name;
}
```

Some methods used:

```
public TransactionStatus requireTransaction() {
        TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate();
        template.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
        return getTransactionManager().getTransaction(template);
}

public Session session() {
        return getRepository().session();
}

public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return getRepository().getTransactionManager();
}
```

Here is the first test, testA();

```
@Test
public void testA() throws InterruptedException {
        // We create the first transaction
        TransactionStatus statusOne = requireTransaction();

        // Create person one
        Person pOne = new Person();
        pOne.name = "PersonOne";
        session().persist(pOne);

        // ---> 111) NOTE! We do not commit! Intentionally!

        // We requireTransaction again. We should be getting the same transaction status.

        TransactionStatus statusTwo = requireTransaction();
        if ( !statusTwo.isNewTransaction() ) {
                System.out.println("isNewTransaction: false! As expected! Meaning we are getting the original transaction status!");
        }


        // Create person two
        Person pTwo = new Person();
        pTwo.name = "PersonTwo";
        session().persist(pTwo);

        // We will now be committing statusTwo which should actually be the first one, statusOne,
        // since we are using propagation required and the previous transaction was never committed
        // or rolledback or completed in any other fashion!

        getTransactionManager().commit(statusTwo);

        // !!!!!!! However !!!!!! Nothing is actually written to the database here!

        // This must be a bug. It existed on Spring 4.0.4 and I have upgraded to 4.2.0 and still the same thing happens!

        // Lets go on to the next test. testB() below.

        // If we now, at 111) instead do, let me repeat the entire logic:
}
```

Here is the second test, testA();

```
@Test
public void testB() throws InterruptedException {
        // We create the first transaction
        TransactionStatus statusOne = requireTransaction();

        Person pOne = new Person();
        pOne.name = "PersonOne";
        session().persist(pOne);

        // -----> 111) NOW WE ARE COMMITTING INSTEAD, SINCE WE ARE ALMOST FORCED TO BUT DO NOT WANT TO
        getTransactionManager().commit(statusOne);

        // ----> 222) HOWEVER, NOW WE WILL NOT BE ABLE TO ROLLBACK THIS AT A LATER POINT

        // We requireTransaction again. We should be getting A NEW transaction status.

        TransactionStatus statusTwo = requireTransaction();
        if ( statusTwo.isNewTransaction() ) {
                System.out.println("isNewTransaction: true! As expected! Meaning we are getting a new transaction status!");
        }

        Person pTwo = new Person();
        pTwo.name = "PersonTwo";
        session().persist(pTwo);

        getTransactionManager().commit(statusTwo);

        // Now we will have two instances in the database, as expected.

        // If we instead of committing statusTwo would have done:
        // getTransactionManager().rollback(statusTwo)
        // then only the last one will be rolledback which is not desired!

        // Why are we forced to commit the first one to have any effect on future transactions!
        // Delegation will not work like this!
}
```

Was that clear?

This is obviously a bug, is it not?

Why purpose would requireTransaction with PROPAGATION_REQUIRED have other than destroy future commits by the same thread?

Why is the commit on **statusTwo** in **testA()** not sufficient to commit the work on the first one as well?

Should this be done some other way? I think not, right? Bug!

**EDIT**
For those that suggest that I use execute method, fine:

```
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
            return /** implement this **/ ; 
}

@Test
public void testAA() throws InterruptedException {
        insertPerson1();
        insertPerson2();
}

public void requireTransaction(TransactionCallback<Object> action) {
        TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(getTransactionManager());
        template.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);        
        template.execute(action);
}


public void insertPerson1() {
        requireTransaction(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                        Person pOne = new Person();
                        pOne.name = "PersonOne";
                        session().persist(pOne);

                        return null;
                }
        });
}

public void insertPerson2() {
        requireTransaction(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                        Person pTwo = new Person();
                        pTwo.name = "PersonTwo";
                        session().persist(pTwo);

                        if ( true ) {
                                status.setRollbackOnly();
                                // throw new RuntimeException("aaaaaaa");
                        }

                        return null;
                }
        });
}
```

On insertPerson2, even if I set to rollback, or throw an exception the **first person is still inserted!**

That means, not one shared transaction, but actually two separate ones.

Comment: Your post shows a lot of code but not the relevant part I am afraid. What `PlatformTransactionManager`  are you using? Instead of calling the low-level APIs yourself (which you clearly shouldn't do) please rewrite your test to use the `TransactionTemplate#execute` method instead. If the problem persists, post a sample project somewhere and I'll have a look. Transaction management in the Spring Framework is quite mature and hasn't been changed much in the 4.x line. Does that code works with a previous version of Spring?

Answer (score 8):

You basically don't use the transaction API as its intended to. The [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) is pretty precise about how to use programatic transactions:

```
PlatformTransactionManager manager = … // obtain a transaction manager (DI)
TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(manager);

template.execute(status -> {
  // Code to be execute in a transaction goes here.
});
```

The important point to realize here is that if you want to have code participating in a *single* transaction, that code needs to go inside the callback. That basically means where you actually put this template code depends on how big you want your transaction boundaries be. If you'd like to run an entire request inside a transaction, place this code inside a `ServletFilter` and invoke `FilterChain.doFilter(…)`. That will basically cause all the code exceuted the to participate in the same transaction.

Only executing the code in the callback makes sure exceptions trigger a rollback correctly, something that your suggested usage of API totally ignores.

The `TransactionTemplate` can be instantiated using a `TransactionDefinition` object which basically defines the characteristics of the transaction to be created.

### A bit of general advice

That said, without further knowledge about all the helper methods you introduced (What `PlatformTransactionManager` implementation to you use? What does `getRepository().getTransactionManager()` do? Why not inject the `PlatformTransactionManager` into the test directly?) it's hard to do any further diagnosis.

If you run into behavior that seems broken at a quick glance, make sure you reduce your code to the essentials and make sure you follow the recommendations of the reference docs. In 90% of the cases the perceived "bug" is just a mistake in using things, often buried in layers of indirection.

If you still think you found a bug, ask *in a single canonical* place first. If you don't get an answer in relatively short time, think about whether you might be able to improve the question (reduce the code to it's essentials etc.). Poorly asked (vage, verbose)  questions usually don't create incentives to answer.

Don't copy & paste cross-posts into multiple locations. That usually just causes frustration amongst the people you're actually trying to get help from, as they have to hunt down all of the places you posted to - time, they could've used to actually help you.

StackOverflow is a great start usually. If the (mis)behavior can really be confirmed being a bug, a ticket can still be created. Alternatively, create a ticket (and then a ticket only) in the first place but be even more prepared to be required to prepare an executable test case, be precise and - most of all - have read the reference documentation :).

Comment: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager is what I use,  and I use a testdatabase, I am sure you have some db setup alrady, just add the Person entity and test this for yourself. I am not using the API wrong. It's just broken. It's pretty hard to share my configuration for the transaction here.

Comment: Regarding short questions, I tried to pin it down to the essentials and tried to included the comments in the code. Sometimes it can be alot harder to read if you try to avoid redundancy in an example.

Comment: I want to execute code without committing, so I can reuse the same transaction all over the place, and commit when developer calls save() by getting the transaction and committing.

Comment: "You are completely wrong." - Well, my code is working… your's apparently: not so much :). So, you either try to apply advice or you don't. In the latter case I don't quite get why you were asking in the first place. Anyway, it's been nice getting barked at. Cheers.

Comment: Well, sorry about that. But I keep getting the same "suggestion" that I use the execute method. The execute method performs a commit each time it is called, subsequent calls, will then create a new transaction. A transaction is hence never reused, and PROPAGATION_REQUIRED is actually behaving as PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW. If the transaction is left open without a commit, i would have to not use the execute method, which in all honesty doesn't really do much. Here is what it does: http://pastebin.com/nVT4t7jv I also added an edit to include an example in my question showing it with execute.

Comment: What I want is to create a transaction associated with the thread, and committed when I want to, for instance when save is called.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, this is a bug in Spring transaction management.

For now, I have written my own logic using ThreadLocal to circumvent this issue. One has to look for a couple of things for this to work though, but one has to avoid calling getTransaction(template) since that will return a new version each time. I don't know why.

Instead, I keep track of TransactionStatus in ThreadLocal, and check next time, that it's a REQUIRE or SUPPORTS and that previous status was something acceptable, not comitted and a couple of other edge cases.

Comment: Just putting this here for reference, for anyone who might discover this hopefully not getting mislead by this false claim: it actually works exactly as expected and documented. See my answer. Despite your rants, I actually edited my answer to discuss the "I need everything in a single transaction" (which you altered the question to) and to actually approach this.

Comment: Oliver, seriously. What you suggest, using a filter is not a good solution, especially when I am not using this for requests. Nor is it to place the entire code in one single block. The entire purpose of PROPAGATION_REQUIRED is to do what you fail to address, namely what is documented: "Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists." . What you are suggesting is merely a patch on something broken. Please explain to me, what should be the consequence of the second requireTransaction call? Should it really be a new transaction?

Comment: Also, how come the new transaction fails to commit, if some previous transaction failed to commit? Why should the next, what should be an isolated code block, be dependant on what others did in the same thread context, and prevent it from committing? REQUIRED here leads to instability issues, where you will not get any valid transaction. 

It's quite common that people here on SO gang up and dismiss stuff and come up with patch work solutions. Seroiusly, for requests only, you have one solution, then for others?

Comment: You want me to place all code in one block? What happened with ensureTransaction(); /** do some work  **/ commitTransaction();

The thing is that most people will never run into this issue, because they will be calling requireTransaction all over the place, and most of the times they are not nitpicking like me. But I am still RIGHT.

Comment: And even a Spring employer has already confirmed that this is an "obvious problem"

Comment: I think we can take this to an end. You insist on being right and nothing in the world can change that. Not even yet another 5 400 character comments. Cheers.

Comment: I am only being right in that your answer does not adress the issue here. At all. You are supposed to be able to call require transaction and join in, or create a new one. So any method can do that to ensure a transaction. I am merely putting it out there that it does not work as intended and documented. You suggest that all code in my application live around your nice little code block, alternative create a queue so all my code can execute right there. That's hardly a nice design philsophy. Plus, I have already solved it in a way nicer way that your suggested solution.

Comment: I tend to push things a little further than the average devoloper, that's all.